Randomization of experiment runs to account for uncontrollable factors
I am running an experiment where there is a factor I suspect that can be affecting the results, I can't control nor  absolutely measure ( ie. I can detect differences between specimens but can not measure it, and in operating environment you only get 1 specimen) that factor ( lets call it factor A) , so I am hoping randomization could take care of it. However, I am having problems with deciding how to correctly randomize the experiment (which has 3 repetitions and 8 runs (24 in total ) ), I have 2 options:
1- use a different specimen for each repetition but the same for all the runs in that repetition ( in that case I guess I would treat each repetition as a block)
2- use a different specimen for each repetition and each run
I prefer option 1, however, I can't really think of a strong argument against option 2, specially since I don't really care about the effect of factor A, so I would be thankful for any input and any different perspective on which option would be better.

Please describe the experiment and the scientific question in detail. For example: how you've chosen to do 3 repetitions and 8 runs, what is the outcome variable and how it's measured, do you measure any covariates, etc.
